AKS: Kubernetes clusters should disable automounting API credentials
I could see the following Recommendations in Microsoft Defender for Cloud

Below is the definition of the Service Account
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: workload-identity-sa
  namespace: ...
    ....
  managedFields:
    - manager: HashiCorp
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: v1
      time: '2024-01-29T17:57:49Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        ....
  selfLink: ....
automountServiceAccountToken: true

and POD definition is
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: ..
  labels:
    app: ..
  ownerReferences:
    ...
  managedFields:
    - manager: ...
          .....
          f:automountServiceAccountToken: {}
          ....
spec:
  ...
  containers:
    - name: ..
      image: >-
        ..
      ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
  ....
  restartPolicy: Always
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  serviceAccountName: default
  serviceAccount: default
  automountServiceAccountToken: true
  ....

as per the recommendation, automountServiceAccountToken should be set to false.
However, these PODs uses the service account to pull the secrets from Azure Key vault(s) using external-secrets(using Federated Identity) as well as adds the relevant entries in the DNS using external-dns. These PODs also reads the values from Kubernetes config maps and secrets.
would there be an issue with setting automountServiceAccountToken to false? How to address this issue?

if your pods require access to Azure Key Vault and other resources, you can use managed identities for Azure resources or the Secrets Store CSI driver to securely retrieve secrets and credentials. use managed identities for Azure resources to let your pod request access to other resources, such as Azure Key Vault. You can also integrate Azure Key Vault with an AKS cluster using the Azure KV provider for the Secrets Store CSI Driver. The Secrets Store CSI driver enables the AKS cluster to natively retrieve secret contents from KV and securely provide them only to the requesting pod

Setting  automountServiceAccountToken  to false can improve the security of your AKS cluster by disabling the default behavior of mounting the service account token into the pod's filesystem. This token can be used to access the Kubernetes API server and perform actions based on the service account's permissions. However, if your pods require access to Azure Key Vault and other resources, you can use managed identities for Azure resources or the Secrets Store CSI driver to securely retrieve secrets and credentials.
To address this issue, you can use managed identities for Azure resources to let your pod request access to other resources, such as Azure Key Vault. First, you need to ensure that your AKS cluster is configured to use Managed Identities. This is typically set up during the creation of the cluster, but it can be configured later as well.
az aks create \
  --name MyAKSCluster \
  --resource-group MyResourceGroup \
  --node-count 1 \
  --enable-managed-identity \
  --generate-ssh-keys

if updating existing one, then
az aks update \
  --name MyAKSCluster \
  --resource-group MyResourceGroup \
  --enable-managed-identity


You can also integrate Azure Key Vault with an AKS cluster using the Azure Key Vault provider for the Secrets Store CSI Driver. The Secrets Store CSI driver enables the AKS cluster to natively retrieve secret contents from Key Vault and securely provide them only to the requesting pod. Work with your cluster operator to deploy the Secrets Store CSI Driver onto AKS worker nodes. You can use a Microsoft Entra Workload ID to request access to Key Vault and retrieve the secret contents needed through the Secrets Store CSI Driver.
Install the Secrets Store CSI Driver and the Azure Key Vault Provider


Assign the necessary role to the Managed Identity to read secrets
az keyvault set-policy -n MyKeyVault --key-permissions get --spn <Managed-Identity-Principal-ID>

Create a new one or edit the existing SecretProviderClass resource that specifies what secrets to retrieve from Azure Key Vault
Example
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: azure-kvname
  namespace: default
spec:
  provider: azure
  secretObjects:
  - secretName: example-secret
    type: Opaque
    data:
    - key: username
      objectName: dbusername
    - key: password
      objectName: dbpassword
    - key: secret
      objectName: arko
  parameters:
    usePodIdentity: "true"  # Enable managed identity
    keyvaultName: "arkokv"
    cloudName: "AzurePublicCloud"
    objects:  |
      array:
        - |
          objectName: dbusername
          objectType: secret
        - |
          objectName: dbpassword
          objectType: secret
        - |
          objectName: arko
          objectType: secret
    resourceGroup: "arkorg"
    subscriptionId: "b83c1ed3-abcd-efgh-ijk-lmno"
    tenantId: "72f988bf-86f1-123-456-789ghl"

apply using- kubectl apply -f secretproviderclass.yaml

Modify your pod specification to use the CSI driver and disable automounting of the service account token
(This is example, modify with your own pod definition)
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mypod
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  serviceAccountName: default
  automountServiceAccountToken: false
  containers:
  - name: myapp
    image: myimage
    volumeMounts:
    - name: secrets-store-inline
      mountPath: "/mnt/secrets"
      readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - name: secrets-store-inline
    csi:
      driver: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
      readOnly: true
      volumeAttributes:
        secretProviderClass: "azure-kvname"


In summary, setting  automountServiceAccountToken  to false won't create any issue rather improve the security of your AKS cluster, but you can still securely retrieve secrets and credentials using managed identities for Azure resources or the Secrets Store CSI driver.
References:

Best practices for pod security in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)
Security for AKS - Design recommendations
Similar thread

